# Fault Protected RS485 circuit

Tags: protection, short-circuit, rs485

I am designing a product for use in the industry and it needs to include a fault protected RS485 interface.
In the industry the most normal voltage for the power supplies in the machinery is 24V, but we have seen power supplies delivering higher voltages, up to 36V in some cases.
The RS485 is differential with 2 signals, "A" and "B", but what do I mean with fault protected? To be specific, I want that if a 20V to 36V source, of a power supply for example, stay attached (incorrectly) to A or B signals (in any way), constinuosly, there will be no any damage to the RS485 circuit. And also for -20V to -36V.

Below is my current schematic.

[image]

- The termination resistors will be connected directly to the RS485 bus installation.
- SN65HVD1781 is the transceiver, which can withstand commom mode voltages of -70 to +70V on A and B.
- [TBU-CA050-100-WH](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/TBU-CA.pdf) is a current surge supression IC, 050 means 500V, 100 means a I.trigger of 100~200mA. It has a typical Rseries of 9.5 Ohms and maximum Rseries of 10.9 Ohms. I wonder if it would be more suitable to use a TBU IC with lower I.trigger of 50~100mA or even higher I.trigger like 200~400mA. I really wanted them to have more tighter range for I.trigger parameter.
- SMAJ36CA is to protect the TBU IC, it has a minimum breakdown voltage of 40V.
- For the [SM712](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diode_arrays/littelfuse_tvs_diode_array_sm712_datasheet.pdf.pdf) TVS diode, the datasheet shows that the Clamp Voltage (max) is 19V @ 1A. If it is connected 20V at the input, it would have 1V over the ~10 Ohms Rseries of the TBU device, which means around 100mA, and to guarantee that the TBU will trigger it needs 200mA or little more. I can't estimate through the graphic of the SM712 datasheet "Clamping Voltage vs. IPP" what would be its Clamp Voltage @ 200mA, so I am in doubt if my protection will really work. Can somebody say if the TBU will trigger when +20V is connected to the input? Or at least with +22V? For -20V I think it should trigger because the negative voltage of the TVS is -7V, while positive is 12V.

[image]

[image]

If the inputs A/B are shorted to a +21V source, (21V-18V)=3V, 3V/~10R = ~300mA, so the TBU would trigger, am I correct?

Regards.

Comment: If I well remember, an RS-485 driver can output more than 100~200mA to drive A and B signals, and this is legitimate. So take care on limiting current.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I could use a 200~400mA I.trigger TBU (instead of 100~200mA), but then the required voltage at the input to trigger it would be much higher.

Comment: I am not sure about your circuit but the RS-485 driver outputs as much current as needed, in order to reach 4.5 volts. I mean, per RS-485 alone, only low voltages are involved.

Comment: How married are you to your transceiver?  They make versions that will happily take 36V on the inputs.  And not a product recommendation, but this datasheet has a schematic of a very robust protection network at the end with a detailed discussion earlier in the text:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2862345fc.pdf

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica  5V RS485 drive into 50 ohms (the impedance seen in the middle of an RS485 run) comes out to 100mA, the driver chip may be capable of more, but more is not normal, Of course in the event of a collision (multiple transmitters active at the same time) the current will be higher.  OTOH  Bourns recommends the 200mA version in this application - the same document is on multiple distributors blogs.